# Got "Fatal error: Index out of range" : show index in list item for swiftui

Tags: list, swiftui, indices

Updated: error: Type '_' has no member '1', if put a if closure(if !self.showMarkedOnly || name.marked {}) inside list-foreach, why?

Code version 4:

```
struct Name: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var marked: Bool
    init(_ name: String, marked: Bool = false) { self.name = name; self.marked = marked }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var list: [Name] = [Name("test1"), Name("test2"), Name("test3", marked: true), Name("test4"), Name("test5", marked: true), Name("test6"), Name("test7"), Name("test8")]
    @State private var showMarkedOnly = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Toggle(isOn: $showMarkedOnly) { Text("show marked only") }
            List {
                ForEach(Array(zip(0..., list)), id: \.1.id) { index, name in
//                    if !self.showMarkedOnly || name.marked {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(index)").foregroundColor(name.marked ? .red : .gray)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(name.name)")
                        }
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.list.remove(at: index)
                        }
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=========

Updated: I found the issue of Code version 2, I must provide a id for ForEach. And Code version 2 updated.

I found a graceful way to show index, It avoids self.list[index]. But I found an error "Type '_' has no member '1'" occurred in some complex code.

Code version 3:

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(zip(0..., list)), id: \.1.id) { index, name in // a error occurs in some complex code: "Type '_' has no member '1'"
                HStack {
                    Text("\(index)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(name.name)")
                }
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.list.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I show a list, and remove the item I tapped. It's Code version 1, it works fine. 
When I add index into the list item using indices(Code veriosn 2), got "Fatal error: Index out of range" after tapping.

Code version 1:

```
struct Name: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    init(_ name: String) { self.name = name }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var list: [Name] = [Name("test1"), Name("test2"), Name("test3"), Name("test4"), Name("test5"), Name("test6"), Name("test7"), Name("test8")]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(list) { name in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(0)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(name.name)")
                }
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.list = self.list.filter { $0 != name }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code version 2:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var list: [Name] = [Name("test1"), Name("test2"), Name("test3"), Name("test4"), Name("test5"), Name("test6"), Name("test7"), Name("test8")]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            //ForEach(list.indices) { index in
            ForEach(list.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(index)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(self.list[index].name)")
                }
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.list.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, don't update your question anymore ... and last update of my own answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@State is property wrapper, which will force the View in which it is defined to recalculate its body.

In your case, if you remove the item at index,

```
HStack {
    Text("\(index)")
    Spacer()
    Text("\(self.list[index].name)")
}
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
.onTapGesture {
     self.list.remove(at: index)
 }
```

the Text inside HStack

```
Text("\(self.list[index].name)")
```

crash, just because list[index] doesn't exist any more.

Using

```
ForEach(list.indices, id:\.self) { index in ... }
```

instead of

```
ForEach(list.indices) { index in ... }
```

will force SwiftUI to recreate TestView (see the id:\.self in ForEach constructor)

SwiftUI will make fresh copy of TestView while using fresh value of property wrapped in @State property wrapper.

**UPDATE**

**Please, don't update your question  ...**

Your last code version 4 is total mess, so I rewrote it to something you able to copy - paste - run

```
import SwiftUI

struct Name: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var marked: Bool
    init(_ name: String, marked: Bool = false) { self.name = name; self.marked = marked }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var list: [Name] = [Name("test1"), Name("test2"), Name("test3", marked: true), Name("test4"), Name("test5", marked: true), Name("test6"), Name("test7"), Name("test8")]
    @State private var showMarkedOnly = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Toggle(isOn: $showMarkedOnly) {
                Text("show marked only")
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            List {
                ForEach(Array(zip(0..., list)).filter({!self.showMarkedOnly || $0.1.marked}), id: \.1.id) { index, name in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(index)").foregroundColor(name.marked ? .red : .gray)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(name.name)")
                    }
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.list.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

it should looks like [image]

UPDATE based on discussion

ForEach different versions of constructors use internally different functionality of ViewBuilder

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ViewBuilder {

    /// Provides support for "if" statements in multi-statement closures, producing an `Optional` view
    /// that is visible only when the `if` condition evaluates `true`.
    public static func buildIf<Content>(_ content: Content?) -> Content? where Content : View

    /// Provides support for "if" statements in multi-statement closures, producing
    /// ConditionalContent for the "then" branch.
    public static func buildEither<TrueContent, FalseContent>(first: TrueContent) -> _ConditionalContent<TrueContent, FalseContent> where TrueContent : View, FalseContent : View

    /// Provides support for "if-else" statements in multi-statement closures, producing
    /// ConditionalContent for the "else" branch.
    public static func buildEither<TrueContent, FalseContent>(second: FalseContent) -> _ConditionalContent<TrueContent, FalseContent> where TrueContent : View, FalseContent : View
}
```

This is about "implementation details" and hopefully it will be documented in next release. SwiftUI is still in very early stage of development, we have to be careful.

Lets try to force SwiftUI to follow our own way!
First separate RowView

```
struct RowView: View {
    var showMarkedOnly: Bool
    var index: Int
    var name: Name
    //@ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if !self.showMarkedOnly || name.marked {
            HStack {
                Text(verbatim: index.description).foregroundColor(name.marked ? .red : .gray)
                Spacer()
                Text(verbatim: name.name)
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))

        }
    }
}
```

Compiler complains with

```
Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
```

Uncomment the line to wrap our body

```
struct RowView: View {
    var showMarkedOnly: Bool
    var index: Int
    var name: Name
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if !self.showMarkedOnly || name.marked {
            HStack {
                Text(verbatim: index.description).foregroundColor(name.marked ? .red : .gray)
                Spacer()
                Text(verbatim: name.name)
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))

        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use the code the way you like :-)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var list: [Name] = [Name("test1"), Name("test2"), Name("test3", marked: true), Name("test4"), Name("test5", marked: true), Name("test6"), Name("test7"), Name("test8")]
    @State private var showMarkedOnly = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Toggle(isOn: $showMarkedOnly) {
                Text("show marked only")
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            List {
                ForEach(Array(zip(0..., list)), id: \.1.id) { (index, name) in
                    RowView(showMarkedOnly: self.showMarkedOnly, index: index, name: name).onTapGesture {
                    self.list.remove(at: index)
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The final result uses now `buildIf<Content>` construct and all code works again (the result looks exactly the same as shown above)

Comment: This answer I consider as complete enough. Approve it as an answer. 
If you have additional questions -- post it as a different one. Because here SO was meant to be a simple Q&A.

Comment: @user3441734, Yes, this code is ok. But I wonder why my code can not compile? just add if closure inside.

Comment: @foolbear we are he not code providing services. I suggest you to check documentation  about ForEach . The closure is part of its constructor and you are responsible to return some View. In your "code version 4" you don't return any View if the "conditions" are not true.

Comment: @user3441734, you right, it works if I add if(){} else { EmptyView() } inside foreach. I review the apple demo: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input#add-a-control-to-toggle-the-state, there is only foreach { if () {}} , it will return nothing when false condition, but it works fine. why? I confused.

Comment: @foolbear they use different constructor of ForEach. try ForEach(list) { (item) in
                    if !self.showMarkedOnly || item.marked {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                } and it will work.

Comment: @foolbear the big difference is that Name conforms to Identifiable, but Array(zip(0..., list) don't.

Comment: I think it's a bug of swiftui.

Comment: it is not really a bug, it is implementation detail. see my last update in the above answer

Comment: @foolbear see again my update, how to force SwiftUI to use buildIf<Content>

Comment: @user3441734 You mean the "if" in my Code 4 is not "buildIf"?

Comment: @foolbear i can see, that compiler wait for buildEither ...  and don't like buildIf. don't ask me why, ask Apple!

Answer (score 3):

It's because `indices` is not your state, the array is. So you update the array but `@State` isn't actually smart enough to update computed or downstream properties of the value it wraps. If you want the index, make that the source of identifiers in your `ForEach`:

```swift
ForEach(0..<list.count, id: \.self) {
    // the rest should be ok here
}
```

Comment: ForEach(list.indices, id:\.self) { index in ... } should work as well

Comment: @user3441734,  any idea about this: an error "Type '_' has no member '1'" occurred in some complex code for Code Version 3.

Comment: @foolbear without seeing the code i am not able to say ... The most trouble went from misunderstanding how SwiftUI works. Yes, there is very bad documentation which leads to misunderstanding and next to improper usage of SwiftUI.

Comment: @foolbear OK, I can see your update now and I already tried it, without any error ...

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect explanation, helped me a lot 

Answer (score 0):

That is because SwiftUI reloads its content basing on original data provided.
You could solve it by modifying your

```swift
ForEach(list) { item in
    HStack {
        Text("\(item.id)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(item.name)")
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        guard let itemIndex = self.list.firstIndex(of: item) else { return }
        self.list.remove(at:itemIndex)
    }
}
```

**Otherwise**, you could solve your issue using built-in `.onDelete()` method (you delete items by swiping them):

```swift
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(list) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.id)")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(item.name)")
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
        }.onDelete(perform: delete)
    }
}

func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    list.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand me. There is no any problem using ForEach(list) in Code version 1. It's ForEach(list.indices) { index in } that trigger fatal error in Code Version 2. index will be out of range after remove an item. I have no idea about it. Using Code 2, because I want show Item index in list UI.

Comment: @foolbear if you need it, use ForEach(list.indices, id:\.self) { index in ... }. in that case SwiftUI will recreate ForEach View if list changes (you removed or added items etc.)

Comment: @user3441734, of course, tap -> list updated -> UI refresh

Comment: @foolbear you missed the point. add parameter id:\.self to constructor of ForEach View and it should work.

Comment: @user3441734, Yes you right. I have updated the post.