# ForEach onDelete Mac

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to figure out how to delete from an array in swiftui for Mac. All the articles that I can find show how to do it the UIKit way with the .ondelete method added to the foreach. This is does not work for the Mac because I do not have the red delete button like iOS does. So how do I delete items from an array in ForEach on Mac.
here is the code that I have tried, which gives me the error

`Fatal error: Index out of range: file`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var splitItems:[SplitItem] = [
        SplitItem(id: 0, name: "Item#1"),
        SplitItem(id: 1, name: "Item#2")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: \(self.splitItems[0].name)")
            ForEach(self.splitItems.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    TextField("Item# ", text: self.$splitItems[index].name)
                    Button(action: {self.removeItem(index: index)}) {Text("-")}
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

    func removeItem(index:Int) {
        self.splitItems.remove(at: index)
    }

}

struct SplitItem:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319531/1040347 ?

Comment: I apologize if I missed the solution in that link. But I don’t think it helps only diff I saw was to use on tap gesture. I want it to delete on button click on Mac. Don’t have the iOS style list delete options.

Comment: My link doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I was able to find the answer in this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-delete-a-cell-by-clicking-a-button-in-swiftui-92c302d9c2e3),

instead of calling array.remove(at) by passing the index from the for loop call it using array.FirstIndex(where).

Comment: Curious thing, to be honest.

Comment: yes it is.  I am thinking it has something to do with the indexes generated in the foreach could be changed(ie delete/add etc) before this delete method is called. Still weird though because when I use the firstIndex(where:) I reference it by the index.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ForEach` code part is completely correct.
The possible error source could be the line
`Text("Value: \(self.splitItems[0].name)")` - after deleting all items this will definitely crash.

The next assumption is the `VStack`. After Drawing a view hierarchy it will not allow to change it.
If you replace the VStack with [Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group) and the next code will work:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Group {
        if !self.splitItems.isEmpty {
            Text("Value: \(self.splitItems[0].name)")
        } else {
            Text("List is empty")
        }
        ForEach(self.splitItems.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            HStack {
                TextField("Item# ", text: self.$splitItems[index].name)
                Button(action: {self.removeItem(index: index)}) {Text("-")}
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Comment: the text field was just there to test if editing the textfield worked. it was not neccesary so I removed that line and changed the vstack to a group as you suggested.  it did not work but at least I got a new error lol. `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Comment: found the answer over on reddit from this article https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-delete-a-cell-by-clicking-a-button-in-swiftui-92c302d9c2e3

Comment: Nice. I tested my code before posting it - and it worked. Your model is already confirming to `Identifiable`. Without it forEach will not work (in current example). What error did you get? Are there more details?